# Does "preprod" count as a dev sounding sub-domain?

Tags: multi-environment, license, subdomain

I would like to avoid the licensing error modal on a preproduction environment. Would `preprod.random.domain` work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't match anything on [the list](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/how-craft-license-enforcement-works#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain):

[image: How do we determine Craft is running on a public domain?]

---

**UPDATE**

After filing [this request](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/issues/192), the documentation has been improved to more clearly state that this is, in fact, an exhaustive list.

I have update the screenshot above accordingly.

Comment: Are those exhaustive criteria? The "e.g." infers otherwise.

Comment: It's a good question. I believe the answer is "yes, it's exhaustive", but I agree that the "e.g" implies otherwise.

Comment: @John also see: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6105

Comment: @John Confirmed, this is an exhaustive list. See my edits above.